# Is it possible to follow another way to perform this calculation steps?

Tags: arithmetic

So, I have an four numbers.

There is they are:

**Number 1** is

```
40008260280899465341031700284668165694305281399205262735419849961365494809955
```

**Number 2** is

```
82350526090533023720340378009795932810949001557338040412858442884672237587320
```

**Number 3** is

```
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
```

**Number 4** is

```
0
```

I must calculate an fourth number, which at the moment equals to zero.

To do that, I must perform four steps of math operations.

---

**1.** Multiply **Number 1** by **Number 1**

The result of this step will be:

```
1600660890704197765354479495339625405951583926360287119453582016817491244540713053191394166818590707196837509107255928642787944538394204779614041567102025
```

**2.** Subtract **Number 2** from number given at step **1**

The result of this step will be:

```
1600660890704197765354479495339625405951583926360287119453582016817491244540630702665303633794870366818827713174444979641230606497981346336729369329514705
```

**3.** Subtract **Number 2** from number given at step **2**

The result of this step will be:

```
1600660890704197765354479495339625405951583926360287119453582016817491244540548352139213100771150026440817917241634030639673268457568487893844697091927385
```

**4.** Find a remainder of division (result of step **3**) **/ Number 3**

The result of this step will be:

```
57596313968696056513592514942606311130102873379708317985822131243580561204901
```

---

Result of **#4** will be **Number 4**.

Can I get result of **#4** in some way, where **none of results steps** will be greater than:

```
115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337
```

Is it possible to get this result but using only simple arithmetic functions?

Like addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, ...?

---

**UPD.:** I'm tried @paul-sinclair answer. If I'm correct, I must perform following steps:

```
step1 = n1 mod n3
step2 = n2 mod n3
step3 = step1 * step1
step4 = step2 * 2
step5 = step3 mod n3
step6 = step5 - step4
step7 = step6 mod n3
```

It gives right result, but step3 gives very big number, greater than written above.

Comment: So you want the remainder from $\frac{n_1^2-2n_2}{n_3}$

Comment: Thank you. As I understand, yes. I want the remainder from this. I'm searching for some magic way to get **Number 4** where result of every step can't be greater than number written above. The problem comes in at first step. As a result, this way of calculation is unsuitable to selected condition. P.S.: I'm got that I must ask about this in Math way, but my Math so weak...

Comment: Can you give some context to the question. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @RowanS yes, of course. I'm trying to create a key pair using [secp256k1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) curve. At some moment I want to perform this operations, but I have a conditions when I can't use numbers greater than I wrote. So I think that maybe that is possible to avoid this steps and perform this calculation in another way.

Comment: @Kechup - I suppose it is a matter of what counts as an intermediate result. If you consider step3 = (step1 * step1 mod n3), then you do not get an intermediate result that is higher than n3. but establishing if that is an adequate answer would require more context.

Comment: **Number** $3$ is a [large prime](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM).

Comment: @Paul Sinclair - Yes, you are right. To solve a "step3 = (step1 * step1 mod n3)" at first I must multiply "step1" by "step1", right? If yes, so at this step I will get number that is greater than a number which I can use.

Comment: @Lucian - Yes, of course. So I suppose that it can be a problem?

Comment: @Kechup - this is why I said it depends on the context. I don't know what is limiting you to numbers less than your limit. In certain situations,  (step1 * step1 mod n3) can be considered 1 step. In others it can't. I don't know which is true for you.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair - Yes, in this situation (step1 * step1 mod n3) is more than one step. Limit is a main problem, if there way exists to be "unlimited", there is no reasons for me to ask this question. As I understand, my main problem is this limit, so I must avoid this to solve my problem. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modular arithematic: the remainder from dividing $a$ by $n$ is denoted by $a \mod n$ (this is a comp science notation by the way - mathematicians generally use "mod" a bit differently). The thing is the remainder is fairly well behaved (Edited to add Lubin's correction):
$$(a + b) \mod n = (a \mod n) + (b \mod n) \mod n$$ $$ ab \mod n = (a \mod n)(b \mod n) \mod n$$
etc. So your problem is to find $ n_1^2 -2n_2 \mod n_3 $.

The trick is to take the remainder first: $$ n_1^2 -2n_2 \mod n_3 = \left ( (n_1 \mod n_3)^2 \mod n_3 - 2(n_2 \mod n_3) \right ) \mod n_3$$

That is, at each point as soon as any intermediary calculation raises above $n_3$, we take the remainder $\mod n_3$ again to make it smaller. Because of how remainders work, this will give the same answer in the end.

Comment: For me, it's a genius answer. Very very big THANK YOU! I will try this soon!

Comment: If you’re really talking computer-science notation, your first two displayed equations are *not true*: if $a=12$ and $b=13$ and $n=5$, then the left-hand side of your first equation is $1$, while the right-hand side is $6$. You have to apply “mod” once more on the right-hand side.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair, I have updated my question. I'm tried your solution. It works, but at one step I have number that very big.

Comment: @Lubin - true. and similarly for the $ab$ equation. I did account for that in the final expression, but forgot to add it into these identities.

Comment: @Kechup - thank you for marking this as an answer, except since it doesn't fully solve your problem, that is pre-mature. It may be that someone out there has another trick that will solve the final issue. I think it is possible to reduce the numbers by turning the mod around: working with $n_3 \mod step1$, but I haven't worked out the details.